# Create a 3d animation using AndEngine

Tags: android, animation, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm developing a 2d game for Android using AndEngine GLES2. I'm willing to create a 3d animation of a flipping card.

Is it possible to create such an animation? or perhaps use the engine's source code to reach GLES native code?

Of course, every other example or suggestion is more than welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @Kalpesh The accepted answer is the way I have done it. A 3D looking sprite sheet was the best way to go. The only down side is you need to create one or find/buy one.. best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndEngine is a 2D game engine, however you can create 3D rotation effect by creating proper sprite sheet (artwork) with couple of frames/tiles, latter creating AnimatedSprite and animate it, to achieve following effect.Example:

[image]

Comment: Hey matim, im aware of this option, but those cards are being created randomly and there are way too many possibilities to animate them all.. Any other ideas?